# Como ligar um Query a um Container?

Tags: banco-de-dados, java-ee, hibernate

```
TypedQuery<Empteste> minhaLista = em.createQuery("Select d from Empteste", Empteste.class);
    List<Empteste> results = minhaLista.getResultList();
```

Quero que esse meu resultado da lista apareça no meu JPA CONTAINER
Estava tentando assim, porem não obtive sucesso.

```
BeanItemContainer<Empteste> empregados = new BeanItemContainer<Empteste> (Empteste.class);
    empregados.addItem(new Empteste());
    table_1.setData(empregados);
```

Como faço essa ligação?

Comment: Giullia, o que você quer dizer com JPA Container? Isso é de algum framework em específico?

Answer (score 1):

Giullia

O que você procura é um DAO genérico para ser reutilizado com diversas entidades, segue um exempo

```
public class DAOGenerico<T> {

    private EntityManager manager;

    public DAOGenerico(EntityManager manager) {
        this.manager = manager;
    }

    public T getById(Class<T> clazz, Long id) {
        return manager.find(clazz, id);
    }

    public void save(T entity) {
        manager.getTransaction().begin();
        manager.persist(entity);
        manager.getTransaction().commit();
    }

    public void update(T entity) {
        manager.getTransaction().begin();
        manager.merge(entity);
        manager.getTransaction().commit();
    }

    public void delete(T entity) {
        manager.getTransaction().begin();
        manager.remove(entity);
        manager.getTransaction().commit();
    }

    public List<T> findAll(Class<T> type) {
        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = manager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<T> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(type);
        Root<T> root = query.from(type);
        CriteriaQuery<T> select = query.select(root);
        TypedQuery<T> all = manager.createQuery(select);
        return all.getResultList();
    }
}
```

Qualquer outra classe que herdar dessa DAOGenerico conseguirá fazer uso de seus métodos, desde que tenha um EntityManager para passar.

Se for possível injetar o EntityManager com EJB ou CDI, melhor ainda.